# Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data cpanel backup restore

Tags: json, syntax-error, backup, cpanel, restore

i have been trying to restore my home directory backup for a while now but i keep getting this error  `Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`  it is a .tar.gz file. I don't know what to do. Please help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and I am currently researching for a solution. I created a backup from CPanel at SiteGround and attempting to move it over to GoDaddy via CPanel restore.